# Clone button in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

Just started with Android Studio.
When I want to add a device, according the tutorials I should press the clone button.
The clone button doesn't work
I pressed the button and nothing happened.
someone knows what to do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4steR.png)

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Click **Next** to create a device
   [image: Select Hardware]
2. Select your system image and then click **Next**
   [image: System Image]
3. Name your Android Virtual Device (AVD)
   [image: Android Virtual Device]

There is no need to clone a device if you want to create an AVD. You can also do this all command line if you like.

Like Sandeep said, more information here: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html

Answer (score 0):

It is actually Tools-> Android-> AVD Manager.
Please refer-https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html